# If a subgroup H of a semidirect product intersects the kernel trivially, must H lie in a complement?

Tags: group-theory, semidirect-product

Let $G = N \rtimes K$ be a semidirect product (with $N$ normal in $G$).  If $H < G$ satisfies $H\cap N = \{1\}$, must there exist a complement $M < G$ to $N$ such that $H < M$?

By a complement to $N$, I just mean a subgroup $M < G$ such that $M\cap N = \{1\}$ and $NM=G$.

Note that the projection $G\to G/N \cong K$ embeds $H$ as a subgroup of $K$, so $H$ is certainly isomorphic to a subgroup of a complement to $N$, but I'm asking for more.

I am particularly interested in the case where all complements to $N$ are conjugate to one another inside $G$.

Comment: The above argument is true when  $(|N|,|K|)=1$ check this http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Schur-Zassenhaus_theorem

Comment: Mesel, I'm not sure what you mean by "the above argument".  The link you give points out that when the orders of $N$ and $K$ are coprime, all complements are conjugate to one another, so the stronger condition at the end of the question becomes automatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not necessarily. There is a counterexample with $N = C_2$ and $K=C_4$ with trivial action of $K$ on $N$. So $G = N \times K$.

To get an example in which all complements are conjugate replace $K$ by a simple group, such as $A_5$. Then the complement is unique, but there are still diagonal elements of order $2$ that are not contained in that complement. In fact $K=A_4$ would also work.

Comment: Thanks.  Indeed, the "diagonal" copy of $C_2$ doesn't lie inside a complement.  I should have tried checking some direct products...  Note that this example doesn't satisfy the stronger condition mentioned in the question, though, since if $t$ is the generator of $N$ and $a$ is a generator of $K$, then the subgroup generated by $(t, a)$ is also a complement of $N$, but is not conjugate to $1x{K}$ (since $G$ is abelian).

Comment: Excellent, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Let $G=NK$ then,

$NH=NH\cap NK=N(NH\cap K)$ by Dedekind rule. Now assume that $(|N|,|K|)=1$

By Schur-Zassenhaus theorem $H$ and $NH\cap K$ are conjugate in $NH$.
$$H^n=NH\cap K$$
$$H^n\subseteq K$$
$$H\subseteq K^{n^{-1}}=M$$
and clearly $M$ is also a complement.

Comment: Interesting. So at least in a lot of cases, the answer is Yes. I pointed out in the comments on the main question that in this situation we know that all complements of N are conjugate in G. I'd still like to know if that alone is sufficient.  Here  $(|N|, |K|) =1$ automatically imples $(|N|, |H|) = 1$, so you're able to conclude that all complements to $N$ in $NH$ are still conjugate to one another.  In general, it's not clear to me that just knowing all complements of $N$ in $G$ are conjugate to one another implies the same for complements of $N$ in $NH$.

Comment: @lie341: Yes, it is enough to take $(|N|,|H|)=1$.